# In XFCE, how to avoid new windows being covered by top panel

Tags: workspaces, xfce-panel, compositing

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, have installed the xubuntu-desktop package, and am using XFCE as my desktop environment. I've increased the height of the top panel from the default 24 pixels to 30 pixels. I've used the Workspaces setting dialog to configure a top margin of 30 pixels, which the dialog promises will not be used for placing a window. However, sometimes a new window I open will not respect the margin. As an example, when I launch the Brackets editor, its top left corner is placed at (0, 0), resulting in its top being hidden by the panel (see screenshot). (It won't respect the left margin, either, if I set one.)

Is there some setting I can tweak to fix this? Or is this just due to Brackets, and other programs that behave in this way, not respecting the workspaces margin settings?

[image: a screenshot that demonstrates the problem]

Comment: Which other programs, besides Brackets, don't obey your margin settings?

Comment: Actually, this happens quite rarely; I can't immediately recall another program that behaves this way.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14203) to the Brackets project about this.